# Android MutlicastSocket constructor problems

Tags: android, sockets, udp, multicast

I'm writing an app to do some basic communication via multicast.  I'm running into a problem and can figure why.  I'm defining the socket according to the constructor in the API, yet it's not actually setting the variables as specified.  Here is a basic code snippet with a bunch of the extra stuff removed:

```
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
...

private InetAddress groupInetAddr = InetAddress.getByName("239.42.42.42");;
private int groupPort = 42000;
private MulticastSocket groupSocket;

netInt = NetInfo.getInterface(); 
//This is a custom method that chooses a candidate NetworkInterface 
//from available options.  Returns a NetworkInterface object

try{
   groupSocket = new MulticastSocket(groupPort);
   groupSocket.setNetworkInterface(netInt);
   groupSocket.joinGroup(groupInetAddr);
   groupSocket.setTimeToLive(64);
} 
catch (Exception e){
   Log.i(TAG, "FAILED");
}
```

I have some test code immediately following this code to confirm that the socket has been created properly, and it isn't...

```
Log.i(TAG, "groupInetAddr: " + groupInetAddr.toString());
Log.i(TAG, "groupPort: " + groupPort);
Log.i(TAG, "groupSocket.getInetAddress: " + groupSocket.getInetAddress());
Log.i(TAG, "groupSocket.getPort(): " + groupSocket.getPort());
```

The log results of the test:

```
GroupSender﹕ groupInetAddr: /239.42.42.42
GroupSender﹕ groupPort: 42000
GroupSender﹕ groupSocket.getInetAddress: null
GroupSender﹕ groupSocket.getPort(): -1
```

So, as you can see, the InetAddress is being created properly, so that's not the problem, but the socket isn't assigning the InetAddress as the destination.  Additionally,  when I check Wireshark, there is no IGMP message send out over the LAN to that address.

Additionally, I've added the following permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml to allow access to necessary services.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
```

Any ideas?  Hopefully I'm just missing something small.

Answer (score 1):

The socket has been constructed correctly. You didn't connect it, so its `getInetAddress()` returns null and its target port is -1.

That doesn't have anything to do with which multicast groups it has joined. Your expectations are at fault.

The IGMP message is only sent if this host isn't already a member of that group.

Comment: According to the DatagramSocket API (from which the MulticastSocket inherits), the getInetAddress() method returns the InetAddress instance representing the remote address to which this UDP datagram socket is connected.    The joinGroup() method is supposed to assign the destination address and send out an IGMP message in the process.  It's not doing either though.

Comment: And you haven't connected it. You've bound it and joined a group. The `joinGroup()` method is [*not*](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html#joinGroup(java.net.InetAddress)) supposed to assign the destination address. You made that up. It wouldn't make sense. You could still connect it, and indeed you could still join another group.

Comment: But then how do I join the multicast group?  As I understand it, it's supposed to send out an IGMP message to let the router and the NIC know.  I can see other IGMP membership messages (from my printer) going out over Wireshark.

Comment: On a side note, I know that the socket is live, because I can send packets out and observe them on Wireshark.  My receiver just won't pull any packets off of the LAN because they aren't directly addressed to me.

Comment: I've tried that.  I'm running it on the Android emulator and there is only 1 wifi interface.  Log messages show that it's selecting the right one.  Alternatively, I'm tried omitting the groupSocket.setNetworkInterface(netInt); line, meaning the OS will select the network interface on its own.  Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this code works as intended.  The problem is with the Android emulator.  It doesn't send out the IGMP message as required.

I was trying to communicate between the emulator and an actual device.  I installed the app on 2 devices and they are able to communicate between each other.